# Access the nested path of the input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

HTML:

```
<div id="quiz">
<div id="question">
    <p id="quiz-txt">Your Name is:</p>
    <ul id="quiz-opt">
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Bob" value="Bob" class="options">
            <label for="Bob">Bob</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="David" value="David" class="options">
            <label for="David">David</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Jack" value="Jack" class="options">
            <label for="Jack">Jack</label>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
.
.
.
.
<div id="question">
    <p id="quiz-txt">This is the final question.</p>
    <ul id="quiz-opt">
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Yes" value="Yes" class="options">
            <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="No" value="No" class="options">
            <label for="No">No</label>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are about 10 of these `div`s (questions) which are created on the go (getting an array from the server).

So, my question is how I can get the values of checkboxes that are checked?

Here is what I tried in my JavaScript:

```
$('#quiz').children('#question').children('#quiz-opt').children('#ans').children('.options:checked').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all that path, the last bit of it is enough `$('.options:checked')`. Also no need to convert `this` into a jQuery object, simply access its JavaScript `value` property:

```js
function check() {
  $('.options:checked').each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quiz">
  <div id="question">
    <p id="quiz-txt">Your Name is:</p>
    <ul id="quiz-opt">
      <div id="ans">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Bob" value="Bob" class="options">
        <label for="Bob">Bob</label>
      </div>
      <div id="ans">
        <input type="checkbox" id="David" value="David" class="options">
        <label for="David">David</label>
      </div>
      <div id="ans">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Jack" value="Jack" class="options">
        <label for="Jack">Jack</label>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  . . . .
  <div id="question">
    <p id="quiz-txt">This is the final question.</p>
    <ul id="quiz-opt">
      <div id="ans">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Yes" value="Yes" class="options">
        <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
      </div>
      <div id="ans">
        <input type="checkbox" id="No" value="No" class="options">
        <label for="No">No</label>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Wow. So it automatically traverses the path. Learned new thing. And yes I'll use the `this.value` directly. Thanks

Comment: Yes, since you're already using jQuery, then this answer is the best way to do it. If you were not using jQuery and didn't care to support old browsers, then using the `querySelectorAll()` is a good one too.

Answer (score 1):

This (albeit jQuery free) solution worked for me. Check some of the boxes and then click the check button

```js
function check() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".options:checked").forEach(el => {
    console.log(el.value);
  });
  console.log("-----------------------");
}
```

```html
<div id="quiz">
<div id="question">
    <p id="quiz-txt">Your Name is:</p>
    <ul id="quiz-opt">
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Bob" value="Bob" class="options">
            <label for="Bob">Bob</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="David" value="David" class="options">
            <label for="David">David</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Jack" value="Jack" class="options">
            <label for="Jack">Jack</label>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
.
.
.
.
<div id="question">
    <p id="quiz-txt">This is the final question.</p>
    <ul id="quiz-opt">
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Yes" value="Yes" class="options">
            <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div id="ans">
            <input type="checkbox" id="No" value="No" class="options">
            <label for="No">No</label>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

<button onClick="check()">Check values</button>
```

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly and it is much more simpler. Thanks

Comment: You don't need `Array.from()`.

Comment: @RacilHilan yes you do. `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which does not have a lot of array methods like `forEach`, so I have to convert it into an array

Comment: Why don't you try it before responding? Remove `Array.from()` and see if your answer will still work. Then perhaps you can [read and learn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) something.

Comment: `NodeList` does have `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Then you should remove the JS logo next to your name :) just kidding, it's a good answer in vanilla JavaScript for those who don't want to use jQuery. +1